# How to login to Identity on ASP.NET Core with Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I made some website based on .NET Core MVC with Identity example in Visual Studio 2019 that uses SignalR and I want to make an app that connects to the same server and has similar functionality. How can I make a login system that works with Android? Do I have to make some kind of controller? Maybe just use WebView and use the cookie?

Comment: Hope this can help u.[How can I use an ASP.NET Identity website login with my Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49466144/13655939)

Comment: This uses Xamarin. Are there many differences?

Comment: No, it's same but different programming language. To handle authorization you send a login and the API will return a Json Web token or cookie (depending on what you are using) and for subsequent requests you send this token with the request.

Comment: How do I get a token from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager?

Comment: @Lightman Or rather SignInManager?

Comment: [search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02ocQhxoo6X-1r65wAruBVIBkYX5A%3A1598842737414&ei=cWdMX8_lGJepoATZ9oKIBw&q=Token+based+authentication+in+ASP.NET+Core+using+Identity+Framework&oq=Token+based+authentication+in+ASP.NET+Core+using+Identity+Framework&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA0oFCCASATBKBQgoEgEwULWmIFi1piBg0qkgaABwAHgAgAH9AYgB_QGSAQMyLTGYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiP4qirucTrAhWXFIgKHVm7AHEQ4dUDCA0) `Token based authentication in ASP.NET Core using Identity Framework`, then connect to server login API via android as mentioned from @Sideeg MoHammed.

Answer (score 0):

yes u have to learn something called API and build new controller or update your current one here links can help you 1- [asp.net API Microsoft tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-tutorials) 2-[Microsoft core first-web-API tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) 3-[simple API you tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04IP3Yl8-64)after that u have to learn how to connect your android app to this API i prepare  to you to learn retrofit in android to connect to the API